# I have a Lexmark C3326 Printer and I am getting an error of needing to replace the black cartridge

Tags: printer

But I generally refill my cartridges. The process I used to stop these errors before, seems to have disappeared from the interwebs. I am getting error 88.40k. Any suggestions?

Many moons ago, I reset the counters on the thing, and have been using a refill system since 2021. Well last night, the printer decided to tell me that the Black cartridge 0 estimated pages remaining error 88.40. So, I refilled it. I went in to reset the counter again, but it's still giving me this same error.
Does anyone else happen to know of a workaround for this? Perfectly good laser printer, but the cartridges cost more than a good laser printer does.

Comment: Please explain more about what you're doing and what you have been doing before to fix the problem. [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1790041/edit) your post rather than replying in a comment.

Comment: I believe that there is a sensor inside of that cartridge.  After 20 bajillion refills on something Lexmark intended for you to use only once, perhaps it is no longer functional?  I am only guessing but worked on printers and print drivers for over ten years so this is indeed an educated guess.

Comment: A quick search tells me that the 88.40k error message is for a Xerox B230, not a Lexmark.

Comment: It's a fairly standard coding system for laser printers these days.

Comment: @WesleyHarris This one is inkjet.